# What options exist for maintaining Android 1.5 compatibility after Fragment Implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that's been out for a while, which allows devices with Android 1.5 and higher to run the app. I want to add Fragments to my app now, but the compatibility library doesn't include support for Android 1.5.

The only option I am aware of for allowing my users who still have Android 1.5 to continue using my app is to create and maintain 2 separate APKs, one only for 1.5, and a 2nd for 1.6 and higher. I find this to be a horrible option, and I would prefer not to do this. Are there any other options? If there are multiple options, which option would be best? If I didn't have any users who had Android 1.5, I'd gladly abandon it, but since this is not the case, I have to still support them too.

Comment: why do you think multiple apks is a horrible option?

Comment: I'd prefer not to make the same source file changes in 2 different locations. Unless I am misunderstanding something, it would be essentially maintaining 2 projects, where the majority of the code is identical. So if I make 10 source file changes in project 1, I have to do the same in project 2 (twice the work). I'd rather do the work one time and be done, but I'm not against using 2 APKs if that is the best option.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't got around to actually doing this implementation yet, but I'll probably go the multiple apk route, which you can see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html. My code base is extremely large, and I think in my specific case it would be more of a hassle to go through all of my source code and do things based on 1.5 or non-1.5. It will be more straight-forward for me to have 1.5 by itself, and fragments in everything else.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can check the device API level and have 2 versions of your UI (one for cupcake, one for the other phones)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
            ...Cupcake code here...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Taiko. I'll investigate this. Sounds like maintaining the GUI will be complicated in this scenario, but hopefully I am wrong about that. I'll know more when I start playing around with some code.

Comment: You can't check the sdk version in 1.5 like this, because Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is from version 1.6 and up. So in 1.5 it will crash. You need to use Build.VERSION.SDK.